# File handling in C programming: What is the difference between below two codes?

Tags: c++, c, integer, character, file-handling

CODE #1:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char ch;
    fp=fopen("1.txt","r");
    while((ch=fgetc(fp))!=EOF)
    {
        printf("%c",ch);
    }
    fclose(fp);

}
```

code #2:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int ch;
    fp=fopen("1.txt","r");
    while((ch=fgetc(fp))!=EOF)
    {
        printf("%c",ch);
    }
    fclose(fp);

}
```

Here in CODE #1 variable ch is declared under character data type while in 
CODE #2 it's declared under integer data type, My question is how come the output of both codes be same? How can we compare character(stored in ch variable in CODE #1) with integer value(returned by EOF)? And how can integer value stored in ch variable(of interger data type) and printed in CODE #2?

Comment: Now run this program with a file that contains character hex `0xFF`, and suddenly the output of both codes is not the same.

Comment: saved 1.txt file with 0xFF and then by using above CODE #1 and CODE #2 i'm getting same output. Can you please elaborate your answer please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CODE#1 is obviously wrong and it is a common mistake done by programmers. fgetc returns an int precisely so that the value can be compared with EOF.

EOF expands to an integer constant value and it is an implementation dependent negative value, but, most commonly it will be -1. So, when the return value of fgetc is assigned to char it gets truncated to 255 which is a valid char value. This is the reason why fgetc has the return type of int and value returned from fgetc should never be assigned to a char.

**And how can integer value stored in ch variable(of interger data type) and printed in CODE #2?**

The man page of fgetc clearly states

*fgetc() reads the next character from stream and returns it as an unsigned char cast to an int, or EOF on end of file or error.*

So, typecasting it to char to print it is fine as long as the returned value is not EOF.

Comment: Here in CODE #2 how can ch variable(declared under integer data type) store character by character getting from fgetc function from 1.txt file and also print that too using %c?